# BottomNavigationView Isn't Showing on Emulator

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to setup a BottomNavigationView on my MainActivity, but it's only showing in my activity_main.xml and not the emulator. Should I be setting something up in my MainActivity.kt to make it visible on the emulator? Thanks!

// activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" >
    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

// MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

// Screenshots

[image]

[image]

**Update**

I'm having troubles getting my app to run on a device. Is it because I'm setting something wrong in my OnCreate?

// MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.layout.fragment_news_feed, R.layout.fragment_friends, R.layout.fragment_messaging, R.layout.fragment_notifications, R.layout.fragment_menu))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this. works for me.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should set up your menu in the onCrate.
Example:

```
val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.id_ your_bottomNavigationView)
val navController = findNavController(R.id.your_fragment)
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.your_fragment1, R.id.your_fragment2, R.id.your_fragment3, R.id.your_fragment4))
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Comment: Does everything need to be fragments, or is my navigation items good enough for now?

Comment: You need fragment for each view in your menu. "your_fragment" is the principal fragment in your MainActivity xml and "your_fragment1 ... your_fragment4" are views for each buttom in your menu.

Answer (score 0):

Call `setContentView()` in the `onCreate` Method.